# Many requests to server with dojo

Tags: server, dojo, request, inspect

```
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TimeTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit.Tooltip");
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
dojo.require("dojo.fx");
dojo.require("dojo.dnd.Manager");
dojo.require("dojo.dnd.Source");
dojo.require("dojox.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dojo.io.iframe");
```

This appears with CDN or with src="",
and show in inspect element in my page a lot of requests, someone know why?

Comment: does below answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

Well, It seems you want to understand the `flow of Dojo` I mean how it works and how it loads its dependencies.

In above snippet code as we can see you are using [legacy model/version of dojo](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/loader/legacy.html)

> **First we understand the `require` and `define`**

`require` and `define` are part of the asynchronous module definition (AMD) API.

You use `define` to define a module that can be consumed by other code.  Generally, `define` will be used in a javascript file.  The javascript file is defining a module.  All Dojo files use define.

You use `require` when you are not defining a module, but you require modules that have been defined.

> **Loading of widgets**

So in your network and console you can observe that whenever you load the dojo cdn link it simply loads the `init.js` default loader file. very small in size and easy/faster to load.

So once your dojo loader is loaded based on your [dojo configuration](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dojo_config/) then it start looking for dependencies which you are using in your project so which ever widgets (`dojo controls, classes, files etc.`) you mentioned in require it will start loading those widget from CDN.

In this case dojo doesn't load the whole dojo library  in your prject it simply loads only those widgets which you mention in `require`.

***Hoping this will answer your concerns :)***

Comment: there is some way of less request? xhr?

Comment: well, the best way to minimize the request, mention only those libraries in the require which you are using. 
How ever these requests approach-on the fly libraries load approach is given as advantage so that your application will be light weighted. only used libraries will be there...

Comment: xhr doesn't solve the purpose we are discussing here... dojo is designed in such way so it load dependencies one by one...